# Java database connectivity exception

Tags: java, exception, ms-access, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I am connecting java to Microsoft access database but I am having following exception

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

```
try{
     String ProjectPath= System.getProperties().getProperty("user.dir");
     System.out.println(ProjectPath);
     String path,fullstring;
     path=ProjectPath+"\\data.mdb";
     fullstring="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" +path;
     Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
     Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(fullstring);
     System.out.println("Connected");
 }catch(Exception e){

     System.out.println("Connected Error: "+ e);
     }
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Off-topic, but do you ever use JPA ? It's really more comfortable than JDBC. Take a look, you're going to like it ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect MS Access Database using Java program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880879/how-to-connect-ms-access-database-using-java-program)

Comment: Have you tried connecting via your IDE?  What is the Url?

Comment: Is your Java application running in a 64-bit Java Virtual Machine (JVM)?

Comment: Yes it is working on 64 bit Java Virtual Machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}` is the name of the older Microsoft Jet driver, which will only work in 32-bit applications. (There are no 64-bit versions of the Jet database engine or the Jet ODBC driver.)

To connect with `.mdb` and `.accdb` files from a 64-bit application you need to download and install the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine (a.k.a. "ACE") from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255), and then refer to it in your application by using the driver name `{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.sql.*;
    class dbTst {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    try{


    //Driver for JDBC-ODBC Bridge
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

    //Establishing the Connection through DSN
    Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:db","","");

    //Creating the Statement Object
    Statement st=con.createStatement();


    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from aman");

    while(rs.next()==true){

    System.out.println(rs.getString("name")+" - " + rs.getString("basic"));
    }

    rs.close();
    st.close();
    con.close();
    }
            catch(Exception ee){
                System.out.println(ee.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Its is giving same exception 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Answer (score -1):

I think that you want to connect in some strange way..

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

The code (use DriverManager):

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("user", this.userName);
    connectionProps.put("password", this.password);

    if (this.dbms.equals("mysql")) {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:" + this.dbms + "://" +
               this.serverName +
               ":" + this.portNumber + "/",
               connectionProps);
    } else if (this.dbms.equals("derby")) {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:" + this.dbms + ":" +
               this.dbName +
               ";create=true",
               connectionProps);
    }
    System.out.println("Connected to database");
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: There is also a possibility to connect via eg. Eclipse perspective called: Database perspective.